# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.support.gms:play-services-map:10.2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am trying to use the features from Google to create a google map but when I tried to sync the project I got this error

This is the build.gradle file..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chamiya.bustracking"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // can update the Firebase

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.support.gms:play-services-map:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: which error ? where is the error?

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.support.gms:play-services-map:10.2.0

It happens because it doesn't exist:

Use:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:x.x.x'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.support.gms:play-services-map:10.2.0'
```

In any case in your build.gradle you have to change something:

1. you **have to use the same version** for the support firebase libraries and google play services libraries.

For example use the latest v11.8.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.X.X'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.x.x'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.x.x'
compile 'com.google.android.support.gms:play-services-map:11.x.x'
```

2. **Update** your `compileSdkVersion`
3. Use a **[compatibile version](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies)** of the `firebase-ui` library.
4. Remove the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the top of the file.

Comment: When I use this compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:x.x.x'  it showed the available version of this service. It solved this problem.Thank you for the answer.